# Get the tab id from the download event

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Any way to get the id of the tab from which downloading was initiated (using `chrome.downloads.onCreated.addListener`)?

`referrer` of `DownloadItem` is not represented.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads

Comment: As you can see it's not reported so the only workaround I can think of is to monitor all requests using chrome.webRequest API and store the tabId's temporarily in a global object.

Answer (score 0):

A problem with the suggested workaround is that when the user re-downloads a file, then the download may start and even finish before the webRequest API will be called and sometimes the webRequest API won't be called at all in case the download was served from a service worker for example.

I suspect there is some sort of short period cache for file downloads and in some scenarios (for example, small files) you'll get the entire download from that cache without sending a real HTTP request out (you'll see an HTTP request in the network dev tool but the webRequest listener won't be called).